# sql IN keyword and multiple input columns - how to combine into a single column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some sql that is not doing what I want. I would like the `CONCAT` statement to produce a single list of id numbers. As it is now I get a column that has in it "number, number". I want one column of integers. I am using the `IN` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT visible
     , num
     , date_now
     , show_message
     , show_exercise
     , show_workout
     , picture_large
  FROM feed 
 WHERE feed.from_user_id IN 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
      CONCAT(friends.user_id, ', ', friends.friend_user_id ) 
      FROM friends 
      WHERE  friends.user_id = 1 
        OR friends.friend_user_id = 1 
    ) 
ORDER BY feed.date_now DESC
```

How do I properly make use of the IN keyword with multiple columns as an input??

Comment: Please provide input data, the wrong result you are getting and the expected result.

Comment: Provide some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function group_concat() instead of concat() and you want to group by whatever that will generate a single row with the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. But is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
visible, num, date_now, show_message, show_exercise, show_workout, picture_large
FROM feed WHERE feed.from_user_id IN 
    ( SELECT friends.user_id
      FROM friends 
      WHERE  friends.user_id = 1 
union 
SELECT DISTINCT 
     friends.friend_user_id 
      FROM friends 
       friends.friend_user_id = 1 
    ) 
ORDER BY feed.date_now DESC
```